# How to do Incremental Learning with Theano?

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano

I have a model which is trained on the large training corpus. I also have a `feedback loop` which is providing me the feedback from the users. Model is built on top of `Theano` and `Python`.
How can I add this feedback into my model? Right now I am thinking about two approaches :

1. Add mini-batch to the training corpus and training it again. This is straight forward but it will take a lot of time to train.
2. Use the saved state of trained model and just train on the mini-batch. This looks promising but right now stuck in how to do it with Theano.
   Can someone help me for the second case?

Comment: Why the second case is difficult ? Just initialize the model with the trained weight parameters and do couple of gradient updates on the basis of feedback loop.

Comment: But do you think both the cases will result into same model?

Comment: Actually you cannot guarantee same models even on multiple runs. Regarding your question, both cases will result in different models. 1st option might be better in-terms of how we train models but is highly in-efficient and might become impractical for most problems. I would suggest you to proceed with 2nd option.